# How to stop a thread from running at the same time as another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm using threading in my clicker game, and when I run my code, the player can buy an upgrade so that the game clicks for them, this can be upgraded over time and I want this to be upgradeable so that the click interval is shorter. However, when an upgrade is purchased, the previous upgrade still runs.

Code:

```
def autoclick():
    if autoclicklevel == 1:
        threading.Timer(9.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 2:
        threading.Timer(8.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 3:
        threading.Timer(7.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 4:
        threading.Timer(6.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 5:
        threading.Timer(6.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 6:
        threading.Timer(5.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 7:
        threading.Timer(4.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 8:
        threading.Timer(3.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 9:
        threading.Timer(2.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 10:
        threading.Timer(1.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 10:
        threading.Timer(1.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
    if autoclicklevel == 11:
        threading.Timer(0.99, autoclick).start()
        clicked()
```

I feel like this code is the main problem.

I want this fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Tkinter has built-in functionality for scheduling function calls in the future, just like a timer. Why are you using threads instead of what tkinter already provides?

Comment: What built in function may you be referencing?

Comment: The `after` method that is part of every widget.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code exists twice:

```
if autoclicklevel == 10:
    threading.Timer(1.99, autoclick).start()
    clicked()
```

So whenever `autoclicklevel` equals 10, two timers will start. In the next iteration these two timers will each start two timers resulting in a total of four timers, next iteration eight timers and so on.

As your `if` conditions are mutually exclusive you could also work with `elif`, e.g.

```
if autoclicklevel == 1:
    threading.Timer(9.99, autoclick).start()
    clicked()
elif autoclicklevel == 2:
    threading.Timer(8.99, autoclick).start()
    clicked()
...
```

To completely avoid having that queue of if statements you could find a way to calculate the timer interval instead of hardcoding it for every case, e.g. do something like this:

```
def autoclick():
    highest_interval = 11.99
    threading.Timer(highest_interval - autoclicklevel, autoclick).start()
    clicked()
```

Comment: When i use your bottom code example, it still runs multiple threads. How do I replace the old thread with the new one?

Comment: The bottom example will click only once each time the specified interval passes. You need to provide more code. Is it possible that you are calling `autoclick` on multiple occasions?